# Update anchor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page with a table.  The table contains th elements, which contain anchors.  This is what an example th looks like:

```
<th scope="col">
<a href="/Admin/Auction/Closed?sort=InventoryReference&sordir=ASC&sortdir=DESC">Inventory reference</a>
</th>
```

What I want to do is update the anchor so that it has an extra query string parameter thus:

```
<th scope="col">
<a href="/Admin/Auction/Closed?sort=InventoryReference&sordir=ASC&sortdir=DESC&page=3">Inventory reference</a>
</th>
```

Now, I now that I must do this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('th[scope^=col]') ???
    })

</script>
```

The problem is though, that I don't know what should replace ???.  Does anyone have any idea?  I'm thinking I need some JavaScript or JQuery code that grabs the anchor and then appends the extra query string parameter.  Question is what exactly should the code be?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('th[scope^=col]').each(function(){

      var old_link = "";
      var new_link = "";
      //Get the current href value of the child anchor tag of 'th[scope^=col]'
      old_link = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
      //Append the extra string required '(in this case &page=3)' to the old_link
      new_link = old_link + '&page=3';
      //Set the href value for the anchor tag within 'th[scope^=col]'
      $(this).children('a').attr('href',new_link);

   });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sagar - that was spot on.  I will accept this answer in 6 minutes when I'm allowed.

Comment: There is a slight issue with this: it updates all links with the data from the first one it finds - if you get what I mwan?

Comment: Tep, this will only work if there is one such link - not if there are many

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('th[scope=col] a')[0].href += "&page=3";
});
```

If you think the url can already contain `page` param in the querystring and you just have to update its value then use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $a[0].href = $a[0].href.replace(/([?&])page=[^&]*&?/,'$1') + '&page=3';
});
```

Comment: Note for OP. It's possible that `&page=...` already exists. If that's the case, use `$a[0].href = $a[0].href.replace(/([?&])page=[^&]*&?/,'$1') + '&page=3';`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('th[scope=col] a').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('href', $this.attr('href') + '&page=3');
   });
});
```